# Understanding the working of creation and annihilation operators on Fock space

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I have some problem in understanding how exactly the creation and annihilation operators work on a Fock space.

We begin with a separable Hilbert space $\mathcal H$ with inner product $\langle,\rangle$ (**why is separable needed?**) and define the full Fock space on $\mathcal H$ by $\mathcal F(\mathcal H)=\huge\oplus\large_{n\geq0}\mathcal H^{\otimes n}$ where $\mathcal H^{\otimes0}=\mathbb C\Omega$, $\Omega$ being an element of $\mathcal H$ with unit norm.

For $f\in\mathcal H$, define the left creation operator $l^\star(f)\in \mathcal B(\mathcal F(\mathcal H))$ by $l^*(f)(f_1\otimes...\otimes f_n)=f\otimes f_1\otimes...\otimes f_n$ and $l^*(f)(\Omega)=f$. Similarly define right creation operator. Define left annihilation operator $l(f)$ by $l(f)(f_1\otimes...\otimes f_n)=\langle f,f_1\rangle f_2\otimes...\otimes f_n$ with $l(f)(\Omega)=0$. Similarly define right annihilation operator.

These are things I found in a standard text. I have some doubts with the notations mainly.

Suppose I look at $x:=a\Omega\oplus b\oplus (c\otimes d)\in\mathcal F(\mathcal H)$. What is the result of $l^*(f)(x)$ and $l(f)(x)$?

Here are my guesses:

$l^*(f)(x)=0\oplus af\oplus (f\otimes x)\oplus (f\otimes c\otimes d)$, and

$l(f)(x)=\langle f,b\rangle\Omega \oplus \langle f,c\rangle d$. Are these correct?

Next we come to vacuum expectation: for any $g\in \mathcal B(\mathcal F(\mathcal H))$ define the function $\varphi(g)=\langle \Omega,g(\Omega)\rangle_{0,0}$. Now this $\Omega\in\mathcal H$, so how is the coordinatewise product of inner products defined? Shall we view $\Omega=\Omega\oplus 0\oplus 0\otimes 0\oplus...$ so that in effect, $\langle \Omega,g(\Omega)\rangle_{0,0}$ is the coefficient of $\Omega$ in $g(\Omega)$?

Comment: You have a typo in your first guess, the correct form is $l^*(f)\,(x) = af\oplus(f\otimes b)\oplus (f\otimes c\otimes d)$. Your second guess is correct. As to the inner product, I think when you write $\Omega = \Omega\oplus 0\oplus (0\otimes0)\oplus...$ you mean the right thing, but to be specific if $x=\sum_n x_n, y=\sum_n y_n$ with $x_n,y_n\in H^{\otimes n}$ then
$$\langle x, y\rangle = \sum_n \langle x_n,y_n\rangle_{H^{\otimes n}}.$$
The reason seperability is demanded is because physics only cares about that case, the construction still goes through if $H$ is not seperable.

Comment: But when you write $l^*(f)(x)=af\oplus...$ you are making the $0$-th coordinate $af$, but then $l^*(f)(x)$ will not be in the Fock space as its $0$-th coordinate is not a multiple of $\Omega$, right?

Comment: Ok, in the way you are understanding the notation there needs to be a $0\oplus$ infront. This is usually suppressed for convenience, if $x\in H^{\otimes n}$ and $y\in H^{\otimes m}$ then $x\oplus y$ is the element of the $\bigoplus_k H^{\otimes k}$ that has $x$ in the $n$ component, $y$ in the $m$ component and $0$ in all other components.

Comment: Actually I am beginning these things so I need explicit representations. Good to know both the stated expressions are correct. Thank you.